# How does binding elementname work exactly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I remember reading a couple of weeks ago that it sometimes doesn't work inside templates, and I recently tried to bind things in two different windows and it couldn't find the name declarations, so I assumed that it was local to the namespace of the class and just bound by setting the datacontext instead. However, I'm really curious when I am able to use binding elementname and when I cannot, because it's far more convenient when it is possible.

edit: In reading that article, I found this to be interesting:

"For this reason, styles and templates both define their own XAML namescopes, independent of whatever location in an object tree where the style or template is applied."

if this is true, doesn't that mean that Binding ElementName should not work in templates at all?  But then I definitely have some working bindings on ElementName within my templates. That is the most confusing part, why do some bindings randomly work inside the templates and others do not?  It must have some method for trying to resolve the name even if it isn't in the template or same namescope

Comment: `ElementName` binding only works for elements in the same [NameScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx)

Comment: which namescope? 

like these: 

  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

but if it's just those two then all of my files have those so then I should be able to reference everything using ElementName

Comment: That's a `Namespace`, not a `Namescope`. Those are 2 different concepts. `Namespace` is an `XML` concept, and `Namescope` is a XAML concept.

Comment: lol didn't realize they were different when glancing at it. That helps a lot actually

Comment: I'm pretty sure an `ElementName` binding does not work if it is defined inside a `DataTemplate` and points to a UI Element `Outside` that `DataTemplate`. If you have a working one, please post the XAML.

Comment: @HighCore: To the outside should work just fine actually, the other way around is the problem.

Comment: Binding is the most difficult and cryptic aspects of WPF.  It might be good to describe what an ElementName refers to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically you need to be in the same [name scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx) (read this). Most UI elements are in the same tree sharing the same name scope, however there can be breaks and barriers (styles/templates) and if you have abstract objects like `DataGrid` columns they do not have a name scope at all.

I've been working with WPF long enough to guess when i'll run into problems and i know common areas but don't think there's an easy way to tell in all situations up-front.

---

> if this is true, doesn't that mean that Binding ElementName should not work in templates at all? But then I definitely have some working bindings on ElementName within my templates.

Within is just fine, that is the same scope. The point here is that if you apply the template and they would not have their own scopes there would be conflicts.

e.g.

```
<Button/>
<Button/>
```

If we expand the `ControlTemplate` you would get something like:

```
<Border Name="bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">...</Border>
<Border Name="bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">...</Border>
```

Obviously we would get a name conflict.

Same for `DataTemplates` in `ItemsControls`, if you name controls in the template that name would conflict with the same control instance in the applied template of other items.

---

On another note, you can bind from inside a template to the outside because logically there can only be one instance with that name or you can give them a distinct precedence based on how "close" the name scope is, e.g.

```
<TextBox Name="tb" Text="Test"/>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="ABC">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What makes *abstract objects like DataGrid columns* special?  Is it related to the visual tree?

Comment: So if some item in the tree doesn't have the same namescope then does the name not propagate to future items even if they have the same namescope?

Comment: @McGarnagle: Yes, they are not in any tree.

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet: The question is kind of vague, i'd recommend reading the linked article, it may clear things up for you.

Comment: @McGarnagle: (They could possibly still be added to the name scope manually in the DataGrid implementation but it does not look like that is happening since the bindings will fail)